# How to prepare large amount of data for vector instructions (OpenCL)?

Tags: opencl, gpgpu, vectorization, memory-access

I'm doing data parallel processing in OpenCL and I would like to increase the throughput by using vector instructions (SIMD). In order to use int4, double2 etc I need to comb the input data arrays. What is the best way to do this?

From

```
A[0] A[1] A[2] ... A[N] B[0] B[1] B[2] ... B[N] C[0]...C[N] D[0]...D[N]
```

as one combined buffer or separate ones

To

```
A[0] B[0] C[0] D[0] A[1] B[1] C[1] D[1] ... A[N] B[N] C[N] D[N]
```

N could be as big as 20000, right now doubles. I'm using GCN GPGPU, preferred double vector size is 2.

-Should I prepare an other kernel that combs the data for a specific vector width?

-I suppose the CPU would be slow doing the same.

Comment: what kind of algorithm are you going to run on the data after you transpose it?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your device, you might not get a win by re-writing to use vectors in your OpenCL C code.

In AMD's previous generation hardware (VLIW4/5) you could get wins by using vectors (like float4) because this was the only time the vector hardware was used. However, AMD's new hardware (GCN) is scalar and the compiler scalarizes your code. Same with NVIDIA's hardware which has always been scalar.

Even on the CPU, which can use SSE/AVX vector instructions, I think the compilers scalarize your code and then run multiple work items across vector lanes (auto-vectorize).

So try an example first before taking the time to vectorize everything.

You might focus your efforts instead on making sure memory accesses are fully coalesced; that's usually a bigger win.